# Не получается запустить EJB

Tags: ejb

Пытаюсь разобраться в EJB,но не пойму как их использовать.Что надо еще использовать,кроме EJB?
Как обратится к функции EJB,помеченной аннотацией @Path через браузер,например?

```
@Singleton
@Path(value = "/test")
public class Bean {

    @GET
    public String addUser( )
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: По какому учебнику изучаете?

Comment: Не учебник,а разрозненные статьи в интернете.Можете посоветовать тогда книги по ним?

Comment: На личном опыте, к сожалению, не могу, так как сам учился во времена EJB 2.0. Вроде, неплохие "Изучаем Java EE 7" Гонсалвеса и "Изучаем Java EE" Дашнера. Но обе ожидают от читателя уверенного владения core java, конечно же.